# NHibernate's ISQLQuery returns instances that are of an unexpected type

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2.400, and I'm having an issue with a an ISQLQuery query.

The reason why I use an ISQLQuery here, is that this query uses a table for which I have no entity mapped in NHibernate.

The query looks like this:

```
ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery (
    "select p.*, price.* " +
    "from prestation p left outer join prestationprice price on p.PrestationId = price.PrestationId " +
    "where p.Id IN ( select id from prestationregistry where ...");
```

'Prestationregistry' is the table that is not known by NHibernate (unmapped, so therefore the native SQL Query).

my code continues like this:

```
query.AddEntity ("p", typeof(Prestation));
query.AddJoin ("price", typeof(PrestationPrice));

query.SetResultTransformer (Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);

var result = query.List();
```

So far so good.
I expect that I'm given a list of 'Prestation' instances as a result of this query, since I declared 'Prestation' as being the root-object that has to be returned by the AddEntity method.
I also expect that the PrestationPrices for each Prestation are eagerly loaded by this query (hence the AddJoin method).

To my surprise, the List() method returns a collection of PrestationPrice instances instead of Prestation instances.
How come ?  Am I doing something wrong ?  And if so, could you be so kind to tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Edit: Additional Info:

When I debug, and put a watch on the 'query' instance, I can see that the `queryReturns` member of the query contains 2 items:
- one NativeSqlQueryRootReturn instance who'se ReturnEntityName is 'Prestation'
- one NativeSqlQueryJoinReturn

When I do not specify the 'DistinctRootEntity' result transformer, the query returns instances of 'Prestation' instead of PrestationPrice.  However, it contains multiple copies of the same instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the real cause of your problem, but you must enclose SQL aliases in braces, e.g.

```
select {p.*}, {price.*} 
from prestation p 
left outer join prestationprice price on p.PrestationId = price.PrestationId
where p.Id IN ( select id from prestationregistry where ...
```

Comment: AFAIK it *is* mandatory. See http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-nativesql

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the type to be returned in the `List` method:

```
var result = query.List<Prestation>();
```

Comment: I've done that, but then, an exception is thrown that the result cannot be put in the generic list.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem in a slightly different way.
I didn't know that you could use an SQL expression as an ICriteria-criterion (thx to the NH-Users google-group), so I did it like this:

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria (typeof(Prestation), "p");

crit.SetFetchMode ("p.Prices", FetchMode.Eager);

crit.Add (Expression.Sql ("{alias}.PrestationId = ( SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE ... "));

crit.SetResultTransformer (Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);

var result = crit.List<Prestation>();
```

Anyway, the question remains if the behaviour that I've got using the ISQLQuery is expected, or a bug ...

[The NHUsers thread that I've started as well](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/478cbf0349c9c232/7a3dd2a72dce5246)

Comment: I see you *did* enclose aliases with braces after all... did you try my answer? And please link to the nhusers thread.

Comment: Yes I tried, but to no avail.  The problem was still there.
The {alias} in my Sql Expression is a reference so that NH can correctly build up his query; NH will replace {alias} with the correct alias that it will use in the query that is eventually send to the DB.